# Is the Hamjaad sadhna endemic to Hinduism?

Tags: reference-request, sects, sadhana

I’ve heard of a sadhana that focuses on a being called “Hamzaad”.The “Hamzaad” sadhana is said to be more dangerous than
other sadhanas, but upon successfully attaining this state, the Hamjaad is said to be able to see, hear, and know things that one cannot physically know otherwise.

Is this an authentic Hindu sadhana? If so, can someone provide references?

Comment: Hamzaad sounds to be a Persian-Arabic word. This sounds to be a hodge-podge of Hindu occult practices with Islamic elements, which is mostly prevalent among lower-caste Hindus in Hindi belt. However, within the Tantrik system, sadhanas of yakshas, yakshinis, yoginis, chetakas, vetalas, pretas, kushmandas, grahas, pisachas, apsaras etc are prevalent with the aim of attaining similar occult powers. The same powers can also be obtained by performing purascharana of the mantras of mainstream deities, including those of Vishnu & Shiva.

Comment: Sri Ramakrishna says one should not aim to get siddhi but to get darshan of lord

Comment: Hamzad, peer, Jinn, Dayan, etc all such Malice sadhanas fall under Islamic spectrum. Hindus often worship these beings as these can be easily pleased. Lol, but in a longer run  it is a painful death that awaits for such sadhakas.

Comment: @Chamundadas Is the painful death because of the misuse of the powers obtained?